# Does .Net TDES do enc-dec-enc or end-enc-enc?

Tags: encryption, des, 3des, emv

I am trying to authenticate a payment card in .Net 4.5.  EMV Book 2 Annex B1.1 says that:
DES3(K)[X] = DES(K L )[DES -1 (K R )[DES(K L )[X]]]
or, 3DES of X means:

> Blockquote

1. encrypt X with the left half of the 16 byte key
2. decrypt that ciphertext with the right half of the 16 byte key
3. encrypt that supposed plaintext with the left half of the key.

which you could call enc-dec-enc.
Can anyone assure me that .Net's TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider does it that way, as opposed to enc-enc-enc?  The [ms docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.tripledescryptoserviceprovider?view=netframework-4.8) doesn't say.

Comment: TDES corresponds indeed to the case enc-dec-enc, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES), and the `TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider` will implement this accordingly. Otherwise it would be a bug. The implementation can be easily checked by using the _same_ DES key K for _each_ sub-operation (corresponding to a 24 byte TDES key K || K || K). This way, two of the three sub-operations cancel each other out and the TDES encryption is reduced to a simple DES encryption, i.e. would correspond to the result of the `DESCryptoServiceProvider` (which wouldn't be the case for enc-enc-enc).

Comment: In other words on what @Topaco said, with a single length key you cannot do TDES. Key should be atleast double length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Irrespective of language, all implementations of TDES follow Encrypt-Decrypt-Encrypt. 
For a double length key, Encrypt data using first block[first 8 bytes], decrypt using the second block[second 8 bytes] and encrypt again using first block.
For triple length key, in the last step of encrypting using the first block, third key block is used intead. 
If you want to make sure of the same, simply pass some test key and data to the library, and compare the value you get from any online free tools like https://paymentcardtools.com/des-calculator

I can see it is mentioned in the documentation. Click on TripleDES in the begining and then read the remarks section.